# Random times unable to rotate

Tags: transforms, origin, mouse

At random times rotating around an object with the mouse wheel will not work. Sometimes it randomly works again.

I've tried enabling/disabling three-button mouse, recentering the cursor, resetting the origin to 3D-Cursor/geometry, changing the pivot point. It somehow worked for a bit at some point, but then went back to not working again.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, exactly. When you say "rotating around an object" do you mean orbiting the camera with the object at its center of rotation? Or do you mean rotating the object itself directly, around its own origin?

Comment: AS R-800 says, what you ask is not clear, if you want to orbit around selection, you need to activate Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan > Orbit Around Selection

Comment: I am not trying to rotate the object. I am trying to rotate my camera around the object. Anyway I just tried another mouse and my scroll button actually might be not working right now. It wasn't a problem with Blender.